# Comparing Pearson G2 goodness of fit test result

Tags: goodness-of-fit

Using the same data set, for which two latent class categories were computed (with 3 and with 4 classes), the polychoric correlation (rho) with gender is computed. Also the Pearson G2 goodness of fit test is provided, i.e. for the first class it is 368 and for the second it is 433 (each with a sign. chi2). Can I compare these results? And, should I read the second result (433) as a relative better fit than the first result (368)?